# How to install brownie on mac os running both python 2.7 and 3.9

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm trying to install brownie on my mac (Catalina 10.15.7) using this tutorial.

I tried this command:

```
~ [macbookdbw] $ pip install eth-brownie
```

I get this error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please 
upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support 
for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be 
found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support 
pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement eth-brownie (from 
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for eth-brownie
```

Here are my Python versions:

```
~ [macbookdbw] $ python --version
Python 2.7.16
~ [macbookdbw] $ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6
```

How do I get this installed?

Comment: What is `pip -V`? It is probably from your Python 2.7. Use `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: @GinoMempin Nailed it.  thank you.